# Как повернуть главное окно screen в Pygamе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, rotate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как можно повернуть screen Pygame-а? Необходимо ли делать embed в другие gui? Типа такие как tkinter или Pyqt5?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/6ay50z/draw_entire_display_upsidedown/

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли